# LINQ Query against Azure table service fails

Tags: c#, linq, azure, xamarin.ios

I have a few records saved in my Azure Table Storage. I'm trying to pull records from a table,for only a particular day/date, for the currently logged in user.

My query returns nothing, so my list is always empty, even though I know that I have 3 records for this month, in my table.

I'm not sure why the query fails in this case. How do I pull records for a specific date, for a specific user? Any help?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 public async Task<Result<List<Alert>>> FetchAlertsForDate (DateTime date)
    {

  try {

       var fromDate = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day,0,0,0); //lets create a 12:00:00 AM date

       var toDate = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day,23,59,59); //lets create a 23:59:59PM date

       var alertTable=client.GetSyncTable<Alert>();

       var alerts = await alertTable.Where(n=>n.AccountId==client.CurrentUser.UserId).Where(n=> n.StartDate >= fromDate && n.StartDate <= toDate).ToListAsync();

       return Result<List<Alert>>.Success(alerts);


  } catch (Exception ex) {
            return Result<List<Alert>>.Failure (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);    
        }

   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the value for `client.CurrentUser.UserId` ?

Comment: @user3185569   Yes, I have. The value is correct. If I take out the second Where clause, and pull all the alerts for this user, it returns all the alerts in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the same query ended up working. I improved on it by removing the first part, where I was checking for the current user's id. That wasn't necessary since in my case.

So the final query looks like this:

```
   var alerts = await alertTable.Where(n=> n.StartDate >= fromDate && n.StartDate <= toDate).ToListAsync();
```

This now pulls up all the logged in user's details.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written contains no obvious bugs to answer your question

> How do I pull records for a specific date, for a specific user?

Rather than a date range you use in your method you can just compare the date part of a dateTime like this;

```
   var alerts = await alertTable.Where(n=>n.AccountId==client.CurrentUser.UserId).Where(n=> n.StartDate.Date == date.Date).ToListAsync();
```

I think you can do away with the second where clause too;

```
   var alerts = await alertTable.Where(n=>n.AccountId==client.CurrentUser.UserId && n.StartDate.Date == date.Date).ToListAsync();
```

If you are not getting any records then for that specific combination of userId and Date then the most likely thing is that there aren't any records with that exact combination.

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions above and none of them seem to solve the problem. The first one with the Where clause, fails with this exception: `The member 'Date' is not supported in the 'Where' Mobile Services query expression 'n.StartDate.Date'.`  The second one where we omit the Where clause doesn't fail but returns a count of 0, even though we have records in the table.

Comment: I have seen that you have verified the user. What about the dates? Are the dates for your three records the same as the one you are looking up?

Comment: So for the dates, I'm drawing a Calendar using a collection view(grid view). There is a `WillDisplayCell` override in this class,which is called right before we call the  `GetCell`.In here, I loop through each date/day of the current month, and for each cell( which is really each day), I call the above function and pass in the date. The logic is, I would like to pull all the alerts for each day, if any and then customize the cells depending on the responses we get for each day.

Comment: My assumption is, when we get to dates which have any records saved, the list should return those records. Currently, no records are returned at all., even for days I know we have records saved.

Comment: Have you tried it without the userId, just the date?

Comment: I just tried this: `var alerts = await AlertTable.Where(n=> n.StartDate >= fromDate && n.StartDate <= toDate).ToListAsync();
`, and it still returns a count of 0. Could it be that my whole approach is wrong? Looping through the days of a month and calling the function for each day?

Comment: I used the range here because the `startDate.Date` fails, with the exception i printed out earlier.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable, but it is very strange that you get no records. Is it possibly a date format problem e.g. the date you are testing is 1/6/16 - depending on culture this could be either the 6th Jan or 1st June

Comment: That may be true. I've removed the date portion from the query and pulled all the alerts and printed  out the first one : `Alerts [indexPath.Row].StartDate {6/27/2016 7:03:29 PM} System.DateTime`. Then I've also printed out the incoming date : fromDate variable - `6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`. They seem to share the same format. Perhaps the time for the startDate records is 12hr format though?